# Consulta data mysql com x Dias para vencer

Tags: mysql

Não sei se oque estou fazendo de errado. nesse codigo a baixo era pra me mostrar  a lista de registros com as datas que entraram na casa dos 3 dias para vencer
só que ta vindo registros que ja venceram

```
       $cmd = "SELECT f.*,a.* FROM a_finan AS f
       INNER JOIN agenda_saidas AS a
       ON a.id_saida = f.id_saida
       where a.id_transfer1 = '$id_transfer'  AND f.id_transfer =     
      '$id_transfer' AND f.status_servico = 'pend'
       **AND a.start <= DATE_ADD(now(),  INTERVAL 3 DAY)**         
       ";   

exe:hoje é **06-06-2015**
Tenho registros de 04-06-2015
                   05-06-2015
                   06-06-2015
                   07-06-2015
                   08-06-2015
                   09-06-2015 
a Consulta teria que me mostar só os dias 06 , 07 e 08
```

Atualmente ele esta me retornado até datas vencidas 04 e 05.
Como poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a clausula Between em sua query.

```
SELECT f.*,a.*
FROM a_finan AS f
INNER JOIN agenda_saidas AS a
ON a.id_saida = f.id_saida
WHERE a.id_transfer1 = '$id_transfer'
AND f.id_transfer = '$id_transfer'
AND f.status_servico = 'pend'
AND a.start BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),  INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Ou

```
SELECT * 
FROM a_finan AS f
INNER JOIN agenda_saidas AS a USING(id_saida)
WHERE a.id_transfer1 = '$id_transfer'
AND f.id_transfer = '$id_transfer'
AND f.status_servico = 'pend'
AND a.start BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),  INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Se o **a.id_tranfer1** ou **f.id_transfer** for um relacionamento entre chaves estrangeiras então não vejo a necessidade de colocar **WHERE a.id_transfer1** e **AND f.id_transfer**, basta relacionar somente um dos campos.

Pode ser que você tenha conflito na hora de busca as datas caso o campo do banco de dados seja somente *date* e não *datetime*, neste caso basta utilizar a função DATE do mysql. DATE(NOW())...